# Given a number n, we have to find the sum of all pairs whose lcm (Least common multiple) is n itself ?

Tags: data-structures, lcm

Example :-

```
n = 4 
Numbers -> {1,2,3,4}
All possible pairs of these numbers.
{ {1,2},{1,3},{1,4},{2,3},{2,4},{3,4} }
```

In these subsets subset `{1,4}` and `{2,4}` have `lcm = n = 4;`
so we have to find sum of all numbers so our answer = `1+4+2+4 = 11`.

Comment: A Question (as on this site) should normally have a question: i.e. a sentence ending in a question mark (as is custom in the English language that we use here). What is your question? What have you tried that is not working? What was the (incorrect) output of what you tried. What did you expect?

Comment: Is this purely a math question? Or a programming question?

Comment: @LittlePanda: I guess it's a homework.

Comment: it's programming question i tried http://ideone.com/1REdZn but i need further improved complexity